# ubuntu run multiple commands with one process

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

On my dev machine, I'm very often starting a lot of services at once (10+), and then at once I kill them using CTRL+C (very important).

The problem is that the output will be presented is only for the latest command. for example:

`$ npm run service-a | npm run service-b | npm run service-c`

In this case, I will see output only from `service-c`.

Running with `&` will cause many processes to be opened.
Running with `&&` will run only the first task because its a live service.

What are my options?

Thanks

Comment: If you are making a service, you should log its output to file. Services shouldn't output to console.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - this is only in development...

Comment: The pipe sends the output of one command to the input of the next. That is why you do not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it

`sh -c "npm run service-a & npm run service-b & npm run service-c & wait"`